# Compile Error: Assign arrow function to a variable before exporting as module default

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently getting this error when compiling:

Compiled with warnings.

src/Task.js

```
Line 4:1:  Assign arrow function to a variable before exporting as module default  import/no-anonymous-default-export
```

src/TaskList.js

```
Line 4:1:  Assign arrow function to a variable before exporting as module default  import/no-anonymous-default-export
```

Here are my JS files:
Task.js

```
import React from 'react';
import TaskList from './TaskList';

export default ({Task}) => {
    return (
        <p>
            {TaskList.decription}
        </p>
    );
}
```

TaskList.js

```
import  React from 'react';
import Task from './Task.js'

export default ({ tasks }) => {
    return (
        <ul className="list-group">
            {tasks.map(task => (
                <li key={task.id} className ="list-group-item">
                    <Task task={task} />
                </li>
            ))}
      </ul>      
    );
}
```

I have just started with React and Javascript.

Comment: Thank you @Lissy93. I will give it a go and will let you know within the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arrow functions, since they're anonymous you'll need to assign it to a variable which you can then export. This example, based on your code should work (but don't forget to fill in the logic within the tasks.map function)

```js
import React from 'react';
import TaskList from './TaskList';

const Tasks = ({ tasks }) => {
  return tasks.map(task => ( ... ));
} 

export default Tasks;
```

It's caused by the [`import/no-anonymous-default-export`](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md) rule, which prevents a module's default export from being unnamed.

Since it's a lint warning, and not a syntatical error, if you were to disable that rule, your existing code would work (but I recommend **not** doing that!).

This rule is useful, as ensuring that default exports are named helps improve the grepability of the codebase by encouraging the re-use of the same identifier for the module's default export at its declaration site and at its import sites.

Comment: Cheers Lissy93. I was able to check that the arrow function was assigned to a variable  as you suggested and this resolved the issue!